# procedimiento almacenado actualiza todos los registros de la tabla

Tags: mysql

en mysql estoy tratando de actualizar los registros de tb_movimientos por medio de su llave primaria cod_movimiento y me actualiza todos los campos de la tabla.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bd_sigef3.actualizar_movimientos
(
  in `cod_movimiento` int,
  in `descripcion` varchar(140),
  in `tipo_movimiento` varchar(20),
  in `fecha_registro_movimiento` datetime
)
BEGIN 
UPDATE tb_movimientos SET
descripcion = descripcion,
tipo_movimiento = tipo_movimiento,
fecha_registro_movimiento = fecha_registro_movimiento
   WHERE cod_movimiento = cod_movimiento;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

la llamo de la siguiente forma:

```
call actualizar_movimientos(1,'salen prdel inventario','venta','2019-04-18');
```

la tabla actualizando todos los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, cual es la duda?

Comment: no se porque actualiza todas los registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu `PA` cambia el nombre del parámetro que estás pasando para usar dentro de tu condicional `WHERE` es decir tu tienes

```
 cod_movimiento;
```

Pero ese valor es idéntico a la columna de tu propia tabla, entonces deberías indicar al momento de pasarlo como parámetro; algo distinto así

```
 in `cod_movimientoIN` int,
```

Para dejar identificado que ese valor es uno que el usuario ingresará al momento de mandar llamar al `PA` y que no es el mismo que el valor de la columna `cod_movimiento` que ya tiene tu tabla

Para que en el `WHERE` se vea algo así

```
WHERE cod_movimiento = cod_movimientoIN;
```

Dado lo anterior, entonces deberás:

- Eliminar el `PA`
- Crear de nuevo el `PA` cambiando los valores indicados

  - Agregar `IN` al valor de entrada al final de su nombre, para diferenciarlo del valor de la columna que posee tu tabla

Similar a algo como esto

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bd_sigef3.actualizar_movimientos
(
  in `cod_movimientoIN` int,
  in `descripcion` varchar(140),
  in `tipo_movimiento` varchar(20),
  in `fecha_registro_movimiento` datetime
)
BEGIN 
UPDATE tb_movimientos SET
descripcion = descripcion,
tipo_movimiento = tipo_movimiento,
fecha_registro_movimiento = fecha_registro_movimiento
   WHERE cod_movimiento = cod_movimientoIN;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboracion, me sirvio de mucho tu aporte.